# How to close a question as "This question already has an answer here"?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, duplicates

A question like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030691/pid-and-prime-ideals) is completely solved in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78006/prove-that-a-ufd-is-a-pid-if-and-only-if-every-nonzero-prime-ideal-is-maximal/78012#78012) to another question, but the questions themselves are not duplicates one to another.

I've seen recently that some questions were closed but not as duplicates, instead appearing a message saying "This question already has an answer here". I find this appropriate, but I have no idea how to close a question this way. Any suggestions?

**Edit.** Meanwhile I've found a similar question and I've voted to close it as a duplicate, but my question still stands.

Comment: And you can't just vote to close?

Comment: I would close this specific question as "off topic because of missing context". But I think I just realized what you were asking about. In general I would leave a question open if it is not a duplicate of another question (even if it has an answer somewhere). What I would do is to provide an answer explaining how the other answer actually gives a solution to the problem.

Comment: This could be an option, but as I said I've seen questions closed with the message "this question has an answer there" and I'm somehow intrigued that I can't see how to do this.

Comment: It would be cool if we could merge responses.

Comment: When you close a question as a duplicate of another question, then the closed question will have a yellow bar at the top saying "This question already has an answer here:". Following this is a link to the duplicate question. I agree that the wording maybe isn't the best since I would only close questions as duplicates when the questions are the same.

Comment: I've tried what you said, but I can't see that "yellow bar". Maybe this is (as I supposed) a feature available only to high rated users.

Comment: Thomas meant that the banner is shown to everyone when the question is actually closed. Until then, it's shown to OP only.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii: Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 8):

Marking Question1 as a duplicate of Question2 says that anyone wishing to post an answer to Q1 should instead post their answer under Q2. This is problematic when Q1 may also be answered in a way Q1 that is not applicable to Q2.

So,  the fact that a particular answer to Q2 also answers Q1 is not sufficient to close Q1 as a duplicate. Unless the questions are indeed similar, I suggest posting an answer based on the answer to Q2 (with a reference there). This could be a short explanation of **why** the answer to Q2 answers Q1 (sometimes this isn't so obvious), or a customized copy of the answer to Q2 (perhaps CW-ed).

---

This may look like a useless activity, but my top-voted answer in November (so far) is of this sort. Just a few lines, but apparently some found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, I agree with Rafflesia's answer, except for one particular case:

If we have an general question with "parameters" that has been answered, for example:

> How do I solve the linear congruence below?
>   $$ax \equiv b \pmod{n}$$

...and someone asks a question that is a specific case (e.g. the parameters have been filled in) of the general question, for example:

> How do I solve $3x \equiv 2\pmod 5$?

...then we should close the specific version as a duplicate of the general question.

If the application of the general question to the specific question is more involved than plugging in a few parameters, then we should post a separate answer, like Rafflesia says.  Otherwise, close as duplicate.